# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned,

Tags: flutter

RoundButton(onPressed: ()  {_formkey.currentState!.save();if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Form is validated')),);}}),

Comment: What is `RoundButton`, can you add where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the question ,please
if u could